# Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in (laravel) Php Storm

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpstorm

I create a laravel framework fresh copy from composer and when run on PHP Storm i m facing this error in PHP Storm

> Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject\app\tests\ExampleTest.php on line 3
>
> cd C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject  Current working directory is
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject'.

phpunit

Cannot run program `"phpunit"` (in directory `"C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject"`): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in the past with Laravel 4 and 5. Turns out I was missing this in my composer.json.

**Laravel 5:**

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [ "tests/TestCase.php" ]
},
```

**Laravel 4:**

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [ "app/tests/TestCase.php" ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way laravel is setup you need to be at the root of the specific project, then specify the rest to phpunit.

1.) alias phpunit='vendor/bin/phpunit'

Try changing your path to "C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject" then run "alias phpunit='vendor/bin/phpunit'" then run "phpunit app/tests/ExampleTest.php".

http://culttt.com/2013/05/20/getting-started-with-testing-laravel-4-models/

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the `phpunit` in the folder where You have your tests.

Run this from the command line, from the root directory of the project:

```
phpunit app/tests/
```