# PhpStorm Laravel 4.2 Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, phpstorm

I get this error when running trying to run unit tests from PhpStorm:

```
Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\etestproject\app\tests\ExampleTest.php on line 3
```

There was a similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216063/fatal-error-class-testcase-not-found-in-laravel-php-storm/33393462#33393462), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726963/laravel-fatal-error-for-testcase-not-found) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172011/laravel-4-php-fatal-error-class-illuminate-foundation-testing-testcase-not-fo) but they didn't really help me.

I can run:

```
phpunit app/tests/
```

from my project's root directory but not from PhpStorm

**Additional info:**

When i add `'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase'` to my `app/confg/app.php` 
and run `composer update` after that  it doesn't pass and 
if i add/require `"phpunit/phpunit"` to my `composer.json` and rum my tests from PhpStorm they still give back the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHPUnit
2. Select 'Load from include path'
3. Tick 'Default configuration file' and enter '/you_project_path/phpunit.xml'

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is an old topic but i was looking for the same problem.

For me the solution was to indicate in the phpstorm configuration for "phpunit" the path for the "phpunit.xml" file with the minimal information + path to the Composer autoloader:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/5.5/phpunit.xsd"
     backupGlobals="false"
     colors="true"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
</phpunit>
```

[phpstorm configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI6kC.png)

Maybe it could help to someone in the future

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a *similar* situation recently - I found that I was invoking PHPUnit with the wrong PHP interpreter and that caused a `Class 'SomeClass' not found` error.

In PHPStorm settings, you can navigate to **Languages & Frameworks** > **PHP** to check what installation of PHP it's choosing.

[image]

In my case, I was running PHPUnit using OSX's default PHP installation, but running my dev site with a PHP installation created by MAMP. When I switched to use MAMP's PHP installation, all the issues disappeared.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help me.